# Strange MissingComponentException while everything looks ok

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I just started creating my first game using Unity and I already stucked. I tried to animate a mace and run the animation when the left mouse button is clicked, but I'm getting this strange error:

```
MissingComponentException: There is no 'Animation' attached to the "Mace" game object, but a script is trying to access it.
You probably need to add a Animation to the game object "Mace". Or your script needs to check if the component is attached before using it.
UnityEngine.Animation.Play (System.String animation) (at C:/BuildAgent/work/d63dfc6385190b60/artifacts/EditorGenerated/Animations.cs:569)
MeleeSystem.Update () (at Assets/MeleeSystem.js:11)
```

Reffering to this script:

```
#pragma strict

var theDamage : int = 50;
var Distance : float;
var maxDistance : float = 1.5;
var TheMace : Transform;

function Update (){

if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1")){
    TheMace.animation.Play("Attack");
        var hit: RaycastHit;

        if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward), hit)){
            Distance = hit.distance;
            if(Distance < maxDistance ){
                hit.transform.SendMessage("ApplyDamage", theDamage, SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
            }
    }
}
}
```

Where line 11 is: `TheMace.animation.Play("Attack");`

I have done everything as it shoud. Here is a screenshot of my workspace:

[image: img]

Where:

1) is the Melee - you can see that the Mace is a child of it.
2) the Melee script.
3) TheMace variable is assigned correctly.

I know that I miss a small part here, but as a complete beginner, I just can not spot it. Can you give me a push?

EDIT:
inspector screenshot:

[image: inspector]

Comment: Can you show the components attached to the Mace object? The error pretty clearly defines what the issue is.

Comment: @SirBraneDamuj The Mace object contains a cylinder named Grip - thats all it contains.

Comment: I'm not referring to its child objects, I'm asking what components are attached. In other words, click on Mace and look at its inspector window (the right-most pane). You should see a Transform at the very top, followed by all other components.

Comment: @SirBraneDamuj sorry, for my awareness, I just edited my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your object has an [`Animator`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.html) component attached. It needs to have an [`Animation`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animation.html) component instead.

`Animator` is used for manipulating Mecanim animations. `Animation` is used for playing back legacy animation clips that are imported with the model.

Comment: hey I see what is happening. Now it says: `The AnimationClip 'Attack' used by the Animation component 'Mace' must be marked as Legacy.
` What am I missing here? :(

Comment: You have to find the animation clip on the model that you imported and change one of the settings (the name of it escapes me at the moment). It's a dropdown and one of the settings is Legacy. http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Animations.html this might help you out